# Is there any software for converting my jar into a .deb file?

Tags: jar

I have my .jar file.I want to convert it into .deb file. Is there any software for this?

please dont give comments like.....you can execute a jar straight away by giving "java -jar io.jar". I need to know about the software which converts a jar or some other file in to a Ubuntu exetuble.

Comment: Please dont ask the same question twice.